# Detecting when job is completed and re-run it

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs, laravel-5.4

I have put my web scraping function into a job and I want to run it continuously. I want to detect when the job is completed, and re-run the job. I created a command for triggering it once.

`php artisan update:catalog` works. In my command, inside handle, I placed dispatch the job

```
public function handle()
{
    dispatch(new \App\Jobs\UpdateCatalog());
}
```

And my job looks like this:

```
public function handle()
{
    doTheScraping();
}
```

Now, if I watch through `php artisan queue:listen database` and run the `update:catalog` command, it works for once.

How can I detect when the job is completed and re-run the job in completion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dispatch the job recursively:

```
public function handle()
{
    doTheScraping();
    if (!$exit_condition) {
        dispatch(new self)
    }
}
```

Comment: From you. You don't want to run it forever, so there must be some condition when it should stop and do not respawn the job.

Comment: Thanks. I figured that out now. I have one more question if that's okay. When I close `php artisan queue:listen database`, and run `php artisan catalog:update`, it doesn't do the job, but it doesn't log any error either. What do you think may be causing it?

Comment: Why should it log an error? The job added by `catalog::update` stays in the queue, and waits for the worker to pick it up. It is a completely valid scenario. There is no error by design.

Comment: Yes, figured that out. I should keep the listening open all the time for it to work. Or use supervisor if on server. Thanks a lot.